# jQuery equivalent of radio button "checked" for drop down menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, radio-button, selected, checked

Probably a simple one, but I need some help. I had some radio buttons and was using the following jQuery to see which was checked:

```
var desc1 = ($('input[name=area]:checked').val());
```

That worked fine, but I now need to use a drop down menu instead of the radio buttons. I tried the same jQuery and also with "selected" instead of "checked" but no luck. How do I get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to get is in fact the value of the `<select>` element:

```
$("select").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select` is just a single element, the `option` tags doesn't end up as elements themselves.

Just use the `val` method to get the value of the selected option:

```
var desc1 = $('select[name=area]').val();
```

Comment: hmm that doesnt seem to display anything (when i call desc1 as i did before that is)? thanks

Comment: @Icedragon: Right, it's a select tag, not an input tag. Corrected.